# Retrieve data from cart and send using mail

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

This project is with E-Commerce. There is option to ***Add to Cart***. When user click on add, product will be added to his cart as well and working fine.

But finally when user click **place order** button Admin will receive Mail with products. That E-mail body should content should display like below.

[image]

I tried with using `foreach` and `echo` data row by row. But its useless .

**Question is** - I want retrieve data from cart and add to Above table Format and then it will end with mailing.  How to archive this with CI?

**Html** Table Format

```
$to = 'mail@gmail.com';
                    $msg .= '
                        <table id="table" border="0" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="1px"  style="border: 1px solid #eee">
                            <tr id= "main_heading">
                                <td>Name</td>
                                <td>Price</td>
                                <td>Qty</td>
                                <td>Amount</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>';
```

**Note** : there is no special code to this(inserting and updating). all the codes are same with [ellislab.com](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html)

**CART VIEW**

[image: Cart view]

If i use

```
$as = $this->cart->contents();
print_r($as);
```

it shows

[image: Array]

**Controller**

```
public function index()
        {
            $data['category'] = $this->Product_Model->get_category();
            $data['category2'] = $this->Product_Model->get_category2();
            $data['product'] = $this->Product_Model->get_product();
            $data['right_brand'] = $this->Product_Model->get_right_brand();

            $data['right_prod'] = $this->Product_Model->get_right_product();
            $data['brand'] = $this->Product_Model->get_brand_names();

            $data['products'] = $this->Product_Model->get_cart_items();
            $data['head'] = $this->Product_Model->check_cart();

            $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('template/right_sidebar', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/cart', $data);
            $this->load->view('template/foot');


        }

        public function insert_cart()
        {

            $data = array(
                'id'    => $this->input->post('pid'),
                'qty'   => $this->input->post('qty'),
                'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
                'name'  => $this->input->post('head'),
            );

            $this->cart->insert($data);    
        }

        function remove($rowid)
        {
            if ($rowid==="all")
            {
                $this->cart->destroy();
                redirect('index.php/main');
            }
            else
            {
                $data = array(
                    'rowid'   => $rowid,
                    'qty'     => 0
                );
                $this->cart->update($data);
            }

            // This will show cancle data in cart.
            redirect('index.php/cart');
        }

        function update_cart()
        {

            $cart_info =  $_POST['cart'] ;
            foreach( $cart_info as $id => $cart)
            {
                $rowid = $cart['rowid'];
                $qty = $cart['qty'];

                $data = array(
                    'rowid'   => $rowid,
                    'qty'     => $qty
                );

                $this->cart->update($data);
            }
            redirect('index.php/cart');
        }
```

Comment: can you clarify your question. are using `code-igniter cart` class to create and update your cart ? http://www.atomos.be/user_guide/libraries/cart.html

Comment: You are not showing any code regarding how you are storing products in your cart. without this code, we cant help you. Provide the code to show us how you are building the cart. Include controller, model, and view if necessary.

Comment: Where you write the code of send email???

Comment: in here  `$msg .= '';` i need to print data as table with cart items

Comment: @Abdulla you want to allow user to cancel the order item form the mail?

Comment: no, just want to send mail of his product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `jquery` and capture the `html table` that you want to send as email. and pass the variable to the email function using `ajax`, try this,

```
    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var htmlstring = $("#mail_table").html();
                        $( "#send" ).click(function() {

                            var cn_name = $("#cn_name").val();
                            var cn_mail = $("#cn_mail").val();

                            $.ajax({
                                method : 'post',
                                dataType : 'html',
                                url :'<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/cart/testmail',
                                data :{
                                    name:cn_name,
                                    mail:cn_mail
                                    table:htmlstring
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

jquery veriable  = htmlstring

also you can use `jquery` `serialize` method to get all form inputs.

https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

**CI ocontroller**

```
public function testmail(){

            $to = 'mail@gmail.com';
            $subject = 'Enquiry from ';
            $message = $_POST['table'];
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

            if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For view cart and receive it as mail use this...

In mail use this code...

```
$tpl_file = 'cartmail.php';
if (!file_exists($tpl_file)) {
die('Mail could not be sent');
exit;
}
$msg_tmpl = file_get_contents($tpl_file);
$to = 'mail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Enquiry from ' .$_REQUEST['guest_name'];
$message = $msg_tmpl;
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$_REQUEST['email'];
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

And in the `cartmail.php` file use this code

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="shop_table cart" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="product-name">Product</th>
            <th class="product-price">Price</th>
            <th class="product-quantity">Quantity</th>
            <th class="product-subtotal">Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $cart_items = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
        {
           $product_code = $cart_itm["code"];
           $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_name,product_desc, price FROM products WHERE product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
           $obj = $results->fetch_object();
    ?>

                        <tr class="cart_item">
                    <td class="product-name">
                    <span class="name"><?php echo $obj->product_name; ?> </span>                    </td>

                    <td class="product-price">
                        <span class="amount"><?php echo $currency,$obj->price;?></span>                 </td>

                    <td class="product-quantity">
                        <div class="quantity"><?php echo $cart_itm["qty"];?></div>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-subtotal">
                        <span class="amount"><?php $ptotal=$obj->price*$cart_itm["qty"]; echo $ptotal; ?></span>                    </td>
                        <td class="product-remove">
                    <?php echo '<a href="cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["code"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'" class="remove" title="Remove this item">&times;</a>';?> </td>
                </tr>
<?php
    $subtotal = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);
            $total = ($total + $subtotal);

            $cart_items ++;

        }
        ?>
            </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: 1. cant open relevant file with your codes. 2. mail just receiving empty data

Comment: Try to echo one product by `$msg='<?php
$cart_items = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {
$product_code = $cart_itm["code"];
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_name,product_desc, price FROM products WHERE product_code="$product_code" LIMIT 1);
$obj = $results->fetch_object();
?>
<tr class="cart_item">
<td class="product-name">
 <span class="name"><?php echo $obj->product_name; ?> </span></td>
 <?php
 $cart_items ++;}
?>`. Instead of including full file.