# Jquery cart data send to e-mail

Tags: php, jquery

I want to send the data from the order to the email + contact form send.

I do not know how to send cart data to an email with a contact form

```js
function load_cart_data()
 {
  
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch_cart.php",
   method:"POST",
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#cart_details').html(data.cart_details);
    $('.total_price').text(data.total_price);
    $('.badge').text(data.total_item);
   }
  });
 }
Cart ....
```

```css
<?php

//fetch_cart.php

session_start();

$total_price = 0;
$total_item = 0;

$output = '
<div class="table-responsive" id="order_table">
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr>  
            <th width="40%">Product Name</th>  
            <th width="10%">Quantity</th>  
            <th width="20%">Price</th>  
            <th width="15%">Total</th>  
            <th width="5%">Action</th>  
        </tr>
';
if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
{
 foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
 {
  $output .= '
  <tr>
   <td>'.$values["product_name"].'</td>
   <td>'.$values["product_quantity"].'</td>
   <td align="right">$ '.$values["product_price"].'</td>
   <td align="right">$ '.number_format($values["product_quantity"] * $values["product_price"], 2).'</td>
   <td><button name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="'. $values["product_id"].'">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
  ';
  $total_price = $total_price + ($values["product_quantity"] * $values["product_price"]);
  $total_item = $total_item + 1;
 }
 $output .= '
 <tr>  
        <td colspan="3" align="right">Total</td>  
        <td align="right">$ '.number_format($total_price, 2).'</td>  
        <td></td>  
    </tr>
 ';
}
else
{
 $output .= '
    <tr>
     <td colspan="5" align="center">
      Your Cart is Empty!
     </td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
$output .= '</table></div>';


$data = array(
 'cart_details'  => $output,
 'total_price'  => '$' . number_format($total_price, 2),
 'total_item'  => $total_item
); 

echo json_encode($data);


?>
email send
```

```html
<?php
$namebusiness = $_POST['namebusiness'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$psc = $_POST['psc'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$data = $_POST['data'];

$message = $_POST['cart_details'];
$email_subject = "Order";

$email_body = "Name Of Business: $namebusiness.\n "."First name: $firstname.\n "."Last name: $lastname.\n"."E-mail: $visitor_email.\n"."Adress: $adress.\n "."City: $city.\n "."Post Code / ZIP: $psc.\n "."State: $state.\n "."Phone number: $phone.\n";
                   
$to = "patrikl123@seznam.cz";
$to = $_POST['email'];

$headers = 'From: domaci@potrebyhanka.cz' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: domaci@potrebyhanka.cz' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n". 
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $email_subject,$message,$email_body,$headers);
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
header("Location: index.php");
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802674/retrieve-data-from-cart-and-send-using-mail


?>
```

Comment: The minimum length requirement is to enforce you provided enough information about your code. You haven't, and filling the post with `thanks` doesn't help us help you. How does `fetch_cart.php` relate to `email send`?

Comment: That's the cart data